# Cómo recordar el usuario y contraseña en un webview

Tags: javascript, java, webview, webview-android

Me Gustaría saber cómo recordar el usuario y contraseña en un webview, ya que cada vez que abro y cierro la app me toca ingresar otra vez los datos ¿Qué puedo hacer?

```html
<input typ="text" placeholder="Usuario">
<input typ="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
<button>Login</button>
```

Comment: Lo siento pero que lenguaje es? Ya que pusiste como etiqueta javascript y java

Comment: @christian Si es un webview, con esas etiquetas imagino que es ambos, puesto que webview es un componente de Android para mostrar páginas web. De todas maneras, op, no es *correcto* guardar la contraseña. Lo que deberías guardar es un ***token*** de sesión que permita *reautenticar* al usuario. Jamás se guarda la contraseña del usuario como texto plano, ***JAMÁS***. Por cierto, creo que tienes experiencia suficiente en SO como para saber que una pregunta como esta ***debe ir acompañada del código de lo que intentaste para solucionar tu problema***!